# How to add SELECT CASE values into separate table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have selected certain values from a join of two tables (encounters, patients), and wrote a case statement so I could create 0/1 indicators for encounter ids that met a certain condition (death date between start and stop date of encounter). *Each row has a unique encounter id, but patient id can be repeated if a patient has multiple hospital encounters.* I am trying to insert the case values to the column of another table (rcohort) with the same encounter ids, but when I insert the values the new column the values do not transfer cleanly and the table doubles in size. I want to know how to transfer these case values to their appropriate ids in the new table.

```
INSERT INTO rcohort (death_at_visit_ind)
SELECT 
    CASE
     WHEN deathdate BETWEEN start AND stop THEN 1
     WHEN deathdate NOT BETWEEN start AND stop THEN 0
     WHEN deathdate IS NULL THEN NULL
     ELSE 0
    END
FROM encounters JOIN
     patients
     ON encounters.patient = patients.id
WHERE encounters.start > '1999-07-15' AND
      encounters.reasondescription = 'Drug overdose' AND
      encounters.start >= patients.birthdate + interval '18 year' AND
      encounters.start < patients.birthdate + interval '36 year';
```

Comment: The doubling of data would seem to point blame at the join, which can do things like this.  Is the join correct?  Can you add sample data to make this a minimal problem?

Comment: I suspect the "doubling" is because the table is not empty when you load it.  You can empty it using `truncate`.

Comment: Or are you trying to do an upsert? Insert new rows, update existing?